# How to delete duplicate rows from a table without unique key with only "plain" SQL and no temporary tables?

Tags: sql, cross-platform, relational-database, duplicates

Similar questions have been asked and answered here multiple times.  From what I could find they were either specific to particular SQL implementation (Oracle, SQL Server, etc) or relied on a temporary table (where result would be initially copied).

I wonder if their is a **platform-independent pure DML solution** (just a single `DELETE` statement).

Sample data:  **Table A** with a single field.

```
---------
|account|
|-------|
| A22   |
| A33   |
| A44   |
| A22   |
| A55   |
| A44   |
---------
```

The following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/265f64/3) shows Oracle-specific solution based on `ROWID` pseudo-column. It wouldn't work for any other database and is shown here just as an example.

Comment: Which RDBMS do you want it to work on?

Comment: I don't think there is a database-independent way to write this.

Comment: I want it to work on all (or as many as possible) relational databases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That was my suspicion as well, but I decided to post it here to make sure

Comment: "I want to do (semi-complex thing solved differently in many RDBMS) in a pure platform-independent way" = "OMG, you have my pity, a world of pain is coming your way". That's like saying "I want to order a semi complex dish using hand-signals in a way anyone in any country can understand". While waving your hands works for some stuff, it can't handle complex tasks in a way that works for everything.

Answer (score 0):

The only platform-independent way I can think of is to store the data in a secondary table, truncate the first, and load it back in:

```
create table _tableA (
    AccountId varchar(255)
);

insert into _TableA
    select distinct AccountId from TableA;

truncate table TableA;

insert into TableA
    select AccountId from _TableA;

drop table _TableA;
```

If you have a column that is unique for each account or relax the dialects of SQL, then you can possible find a single query solution.

Comment: Yes, this solution is all-over SO.